# how to add some minutes in time in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I have `time in String like 6:55` and I want to add some minutes before saving it into database.
So suppose if I add `10 minutes in it`, it should become `7:05`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat class to convert the string into Date

Comment: but how to add time in Date ???? And there is no parse method in date for blackberry

Comment: A commonly used solution to parse a string into a date/time is to use the `HttpDateParser.parse()` method to get a `long`, then you can construct a `Date` or a `Calendar` from that. Since your string is so simple, though, it would be easier to just parse it yourself using `String.substring()`, `Integer.parseInt()`, and `Calendar.set()`.

Comment: when i am using this `HttpDateParser.parse(String)` it is returning 0;`Date date = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse(time to convert))`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the time is like hh:mm then use this static method it works fine

```
public static String AfterTimeIncrement(String Ptime,long Minutes){//Ptime should 12 houres like 12:10 
            String str1=Ptime;
            System.out.println("startTime========"+str1);
            String hours=str1.substring(0,str1.indexOf(':'));
            String minutes=str1.substring(str1.indexOf(':')+1);
            long hours1=Long.parseLong(hours);
            long minutes1=Long.parseLong(minutes);
            long minutes2=minutes1+Minutes;
            String endTime="";
            int i=(int) (minutes2%60);//60)n(j == i
            int j=(int) (minutes2/60);

            int houres2=(int)(hours1+j);

            int k=(int)(houres2%12);
            int l=(int)(houres2/12);

            if(houres2<=12){

            }else{
               houres2=k;
            }
            if(i<10){
               endTime=(houres2)+":0"+i;
            }else{
               endTime=(houres2)+":"+i;
            }

            System.out.println("endTime========"+endTime);
            return endTime;
        }
```

for 24 hours just chage above small part like following

```
           int k=(int)(houres2%24);
            int l=(int)(houres2/24);

            if(houres2<24){

            }else{
               houres2=k;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Calendar` and do

`cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, someMinToAdd);`

Comment: thanks for reply but it is not supported in blackberry jde .. i tried it but the method is not supported in blackberry

Comment: then simply perform calculation with millisecond `new Date(new Date().getTime()+1000*60)` something like this

Comment: Try `cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 10);`